# How to redirect urls from a central database

Tags: xpages

I'm converting an old Notes app to xpages and ran into a problem.  The app is a sort of bookmark app.  A user selects a 'bookmark' button and I store the doc's db and unid dbs in a document in this bookmark db.  When the doc is created, a redirect is created so when the bookmark doc is opened, it automatically launches the doc that was bookmarked.

It works fine with a regular Notes view but I want to replace the Notes view with a xapge containing a view control.  So I created a xpage view and linked one of the columns.  How do I get a handle on the selected/clicked-on document.  If I can get to that, it'll be easy to redirect the page to the intended document.

I tried the column's onclick event to get 'currentDocument' but it doesn't look like it's available there.  Any other ideas?

thanks
Clem

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a repeat control for this? I think it might be easier and provide some better functionality with a repeat.

So lets say you have a simple repeat. Inside the repeat put a table (put the first row outside the repeat). and then use an event on the second row so when you click it opens a page you specify with the documentID of that item. Here is some code that has a very simple one column table. Take a look at Notesin9 and the xpages cheatsheet for some details and better examples.

```
<xp:table styleClass="table table-hover">


        <xp:tr id="tr1" >
            <xp:td>Name of Row</xp:td>
        </xp:tr>

<xp:repeat id="repeat2" rows="30" value="#{view3}"
            var="rowData">


        <xp:tr id="tr2">
            <xp:td>
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                        value="#{rowData.fieldName}">
                    </xp:text>
            </xp:td>

          <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                        <xp:openPage name="/yourxpages.xsp"
                            target="openDocument"
                            documentId="#{javascript:rowData.getNoteID()}">
                        </xp:openPage>
            </xp:this.action>
          </xp:eventHandler>

            </xp:tr>

        </xp:repeat>

 </xp:table>
```

Comment: I started down this road but couldn't get it to work.  I'll try it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions. I don't use viewPanels for much anymore. Repeats are too powerful. You can make them look really good even using just the normal oneUI CSS, but of course bootstrap looks even better.

Answer (score 0):

Format your first column as checkbox and then you can use

getComponent("view1").getSelectedIds()

to get a handle in the selected documents

Comment: that worked!! :-)  Tho i had to use "viewPanel1" instead of "view1" as the component to check.  Thanks!

Comment: "view1" is the name I give the view panel component:-)